# How to import library (Actionbarhserlock) to Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

So, I just switched to Android Studio. I imported my projects and they are all working fine. My problem is that I don't have a clue on how to import librarys (ActionBarSherlock, SlidingMenu...). I read a few posts about it but I didn't understand this gradle and maven thing. I'm not asking for a guide, if someone could point me the directions I would be gratefull.

Edit:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.0"
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple add this to your app's `build.gradle` (the inner most one):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Then you press the `Sync Projects with Gradle Files` button below the menu bar. If in the future you need to add other libraries that are in maven central, you could use [Gradle Please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/).

Comment: I did it, but gives me a 'Unresolved depencecies', Error:com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0.

Comment: Can you edit you question and post how your `build.gradle` looks?

Comment: I was able to fixed it, this helped me to understand (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Gradle-Sample/blob/master/build.gradle) the build.gradle. You pointed me in the right direction, so thanks friend.